# R aggregation with duplicates?

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
Year  Value
===========
1999  A
2000  A
2001  B
2002  B
2003  A
2004  A
```

I need to get the following output:

```
"Min Year"  "Max Year" Value
============================
1999        2000       A 
2001        2002       B
2003        2004       A
```

Thus, I have grouping duplicates and using `aggregate` out-of-the-box won't work:

```
> df
  Year Value
1 1999     A
2 2000     A
3 2001     B
4 2002     B
5 2003     A
6 2004     A
> aggregate(Year ~ Value, df, min)
  Value Year
1     A 1999
2     B 2001
> aggregate(Year ~ Value, df, max)
  Value Year
1     A 2004
2     B 2002
```

What function would help accomplish this without using loops?

Comment: So a consecutive run of `Value` defines the group, yes?

Comment: @Spacedman yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index

```
indx <- setNames(cumsum(c(T,df$Value[-1]!=df$Value[-length(df$Value)])),df$Value)
```

?aggregate on that index

```
res <- aggregate(Year~indx, df,FUN=function(x) c(Min=min(x), Max=max(x)))
res$indx <- names(res$indx)
 res[,2:3] <- as.data.frame(res[,2])
```

change the colnames accordingly

```
 colnames(res) <- c("Value", "Min Year", "Max Year")
 res
 #  Value Min Year Max Year
 # 1     A     1999     2000
 # 2     B     2001     2002
 # 3     A     2003     2004
```

Comment: Instead of the `cumsum` you can use `rle`: `reps = rle(as.character(df$Value)) ; setNames(rep(1:length(reps$values), reps$lengths),df$Value)` gets you `indx`. FWIW.

Comment: @Spacedman, thanks. I was about to use `rle`, but David already came up with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `rle` (only once!)

```
reps <- rle(as.character(df$Value))
temp <- data.frame(t(sapply(c(1, cumsum(reps$lengths)), function(x) range(df$Year[(x - 1) : x])))[-1, ], reps$values)
colnames(temp) <- c("Min Year", "Max Year", "Value")

#   Min Year Max Year Value
# 1     1999     2000     A
# 2     2001     2002     B
# 3     2003     2004     A
```

Comment: You mean "using rle twice". A properly practical solution would be a two-liner... Or see my rle partial solution in comments.

Comment: @Spacedman, I thought about that, but didn't think it matters too much. I also prefer to write as less lines as possible, but whatever, I'll edit it